# Close chrome from python, kill the process

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, process

I want in the program below to close the process I open in the beginning, ¿How could I kill it in order to close the chrome browser window?
Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222 --incognito', shell=True)
driver_path = 'chromedriver.exe'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=options)
driver.get('myurl')
#Here I would like to kill the process I opened above, close chrome and quit selenium
```

Comment: isn't closing when you close the python script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be achievable via `.kill()`:

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen(...)
# Do stuff...
proc.kill()
```